# How to make a laravel 5 view composer

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-5, global-variables

I'm still learning Laravel and I'm working on a small project to help me understand better. In the project, I am in need of a global array, so that I may display it or its attributes on every view rendered. sort of on a notification bar, so that each page the user visits, he/she can see the number of notifications (which have been fetched in the background and are stored in the array).

I have done some research, and realized that I have to fetch and compile the array in a view composer I think. But everywhere I go, I cant seem to understand how to make a view composer.

I need to fetch the relevant rows from the database table, and make the resulting array available to each view rendered (I'm thinking attaching it somehow to my layouts/default.blade.php file.). Please help, any and all advice is greatly appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now inject services on your view

More info here: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/2

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That is EXACTLY what I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Sub-Views of laravel blade. I guess your functionality is like a sidebar or like a top bar which will be rendered at every page.

```
//Your Controller pass data

class YOUR_CONTROLLER extends Controller {

  public function index()
  {
    $data = YOUR_DATA;
    return view('YOUR_VIEW_FILE', get_defined_vars());
  }

}

//In Your View File

@extends('LAYOUTS_FILE')

@section('YOUR_SECTION')
  @include('YOUR_SUB_VIEW_FOR_NOTIFICATION')//You need not pass any data passed all data will be available to this sub view.
@endsection

In your sub view

//Do what ever you want looping logic rendering HTML etc.

//In your layout file just yield or render the section that's it

@yield('YOUR_SECTION')
```

More explanation can be found [Including Sub-Views](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures)